# How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?

Tags: mysql, syntax, alter

MySQL 5.0.45

What is the syntax to alter a table to allow a column to be null, alternately what's wrong with this:

```
ALTER mytable MODIFY mycolumn varchar(255) null;
```

I interpreted the manual as  just run the above and it would recreate the column, this time allowing null. The server is telling me I have syntactical errors. I just don't see them.

Comment: column is not unique or anything else like that

Answer (score 762, accepted):

You want the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn VARCHAR(255);
```

Columns are nullable by default.  As long as the column is not declared `UNIQUE` or `NOT NULL`, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: There's an edge case which is the `TIMESTAMP` type, which depending on your MySQL version and config can be `NOT NULL` specifying `NULL` as suggested by @ConroyP is more correct.

Comment: This did not work for me! The column did not change. Maybe because I had a constraint to another table where the column was used (when not null).

Answer (score 353):

Your syntax error is caused by a missing "table" in the query

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn varchar(255) null;
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer - whilst the NULL clause isn't required, there's nothing wrong with providing it. The missing TABLE from the ALTER TABLE statement was the real problem.

Comment: @SamStephens and Xofo: There is a primary and secondary ("alternately") question. This is the correct answer to the secondary question while the accepted answer is the correct answer to the primary one.

Comment: @SamStephens Just because there's nothing wrong with providing `NULL`, it doesn't make this answer any more "correct" than the accepted answer? Knowing that columns are nullable by default (as mentioned in the accepted answer) is helpful in regards to this particular question.

Comment: OP doesn't know why their statement didn't work. This answer explains why.

Answer (score 46):

My solution:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name type DEFAULT NULL
```

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE CHANGE date date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 10):

My solution is the same as @Krishnrohit:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `column_current_name` `new_column_name` DATETIME NULL;
```

I actually had the column set as `NOT NULL` but with the above query it was changed to `NULL`.

P.S. I know this an old thread but nobody seems to acknowledge that `CHANGE` is also correct.

Answer (score 8):

Under some circumstances (if you get "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;...") you need to do

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mytable.mycolumn varchar(255);
```

Answer (score -11):

Use:
`ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn VARCHAR(255);`

Comment: It would be better if your answer provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since Daniel Spiewak already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)