# Removing NOT NULL restriction from column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null, alter

How can I alter a column whose restricted to NOT NULL to accept NULL values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

just modify it and put in the old type and leave off the not null

```
alter table table_name modify column foo int;
```

Comment: Will there be a Problem if the column is not empty?

Comment: not in mysql. in other dbms, such as oracle, it will not allow you alter a nonempty column, but mysql automagically casts things around for you when you alter columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response(s).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table is table_name, column is column_name and its defined as varchar(200):

```
alter table table_name modify column column_name varchar(200) default null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn varchar(255) null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

`ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY columnName varchar2(100)`

Replace `tableName` with your table name and `columnName` with your column name and also `varchar2(100)` to whatever data type you're using for this column