# mySQL DROP NOT NULL not working

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-error-1064

I'm reading The definitive guide to django, and there's a line where i have to tell mySQL that a column can have a null value.

The book uses this

```
ALTER TABLE books_book ALTER COLUMN publication_date DROP NOT NULL;
```

But when i run it i get this message :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'NOT NULL' at line 1

What's going on ? I'm a beginner so i can't easily diagnose mySQL error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `DROP` with column names, index names, and constraint names but not with a *condition* on data. I don't think `NOT NULL` is a named constraint and hence is the error.

You can't use `ALTER COLUMN` to drop a column's NOT NULL definition but to `DROP DEFAULT`.

**Examples**:

```
ALTER TABLE books_book ALTER COLUMN publication_date DROP DEFAULT;  
ALTER TABLE books_book ALTER COLUMN publication_date SET DEFAULT TODAY();
```

If you are looking to remove the `NOT NULL` definition on the column, you should use either `MODIFY` or `CHANGE` syntax with `ALTER TABLE`.

**Examples**:

```
ALTER TABLE books_book MODIFY COLUMN publication_date DATE NULL;  
ALTER TABLE books_book CHANGE COLUMN publication_date new_name DATE NULL;
```

**Refer To**: [***ALTER TABLE Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this syntax is wrong.

If you only want to allow a column to sometimes contain null values, then it's already the default behavior.

Check if your table definition forbids nulls with

```
show create table
```

If it hasn't a default behavior, you will see UNIQUE and/or NOT NULL constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The most minimalistic correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE books_book ALTER COLUMN publication_date column_type NULL;
```

Replace column_type with the current type of publication_date, if you have any other specifiers for that column you should add in those as well. Supposing it's a date as the name suggests:

```
ALTER TABLE books_book ALTER COLUMN publication_date DATE NULL;
```

You can see how to recreate the column using mysqldump or from an administration interface by exporting the table (or as @mbarthelemy suggested with `show create table books_book;`), get the syntax for creating the column from there and and use it in `alter table`, but replace NOT NULL with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

This one works perfectly fine for MySQL 5.5

`ALTER TABLE books_book CHANGE publication_date publication_date DATE;`