# Symfony2 and Doctrine, Column cannot be null with OneToOne relationships

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, one-to-one

Here is an entity (**EDITED: full file content**)

```
// Eve\MoonBundle\Entity\MoonMaterial.php

namespace Eve\MoonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

//use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="_moon_material")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class MoonMaterial
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->invTypes_byTypeID = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // relations start

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Eve\DumpBundle\Entity\invTypes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="typeID", referencedColumnName="typeID")
     */
    private $invTypes_byTypeID;

    public function get_invTypes_byTypeID()
    {
        return $this->invTypes_byTypeID;
    }

    // relations end

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="userID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $userID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="moonID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $moonID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="typeID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $typeID;

    /**
     * Set userID
     *
     * @param integer $userID
     * @return MoonMaterial
     */
    public function setUserID($userID)
    {
        $this->userID = $userID;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUserID()
    {
        return $this->userID;
    }

    /**
     * Set moonID
     *
     * @param integer $moonID
     * @return MoonMaterial
     */
    public function setMoonID($moonID)
    {
        $this->moonID = $moonID;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get moonID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMoonID()
    {
        return $this->moonID;
    }

    /**
     * Set typeID
     *
     * @param integer $typeID
     * @return MoonMaterial
     */
    public function setTypeID($typeID)
    {
        $this->typeID = $typeID;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typeID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getTypeID()
    {
        return $this->typeID;
    }

}
```

code in controller (**EDITED**)

```
// Eve\MoonBundle\Controller\IndexController.php
namespace Eve\MoonBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Eve\MoonBundle\Entity\MoonMaterial;

class IndexController extends Controller
{

    public function defaultAction($moonName)
    {
        // ...
        $dc = $this->getDoctrine();
        $form = $this
            ->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('typeID', 'choice', $choiceSettings)
            ->getForm();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('post'))
        {
            $form->bind($this->getRequest());
            {
                $data = $form->getData();
                $typeID = $data['typeID'];

                if (is_int($typeID))
                {
                    $em = $dc->getEntityManager();
                    $mm = $em->getRepository('EveMoonBundle:MoonMaterial');

                    $result = $mm->findOneBy(array(
                            'userID' => $this->getUser()->getID(),
                            'typeID' => $typeID,
                            'moonID' => $moon->getItemID()));

                    if ($result)
                    {
                        $em->remove($result);
                        $em->flush();
                    }

                    $moonMaterial = new MoonMaterial();
                    $moonMaterial
                        ->setUserID($this->getUser()->getID())
                        ->setTypeID($typeID)
                        ->setMoonID($moon->getItemID());


                    $em->persist($moonMaterial);
                    $em->flush();
                }
            }
        }

        $twig = 'EveMoonBundle:Index:default.html.twig';
        return $this->render($twig, array(
                'formAddMoonMaterial' => $form->createView()));
    }

}
```

when i try this, i get error

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO _moon_material (userID, moonID, typeID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params {"1":38,"2":40001583,"3":null}:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'typeID' cannot be null
```

but when i comment the OneToOne (code above) relationship it work correctly, so main trouble is in description OneToOne relationship... pls help to deal with it

what i want, i want rewrite entry if exist in table "_moon_material" or simply write it if not

ps: i need that relation only for "read" (join name by id)

Comment: Please post the full classes of invTypes and MoonMaterial. The mistake is obviously not where you think it is

Comment: look at EDITED code, i changed it

Comment: so what do you think? where is trouble? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know why, i can't do unidirectional relations, so i solved it by bidirectional by adding some code to invTypes table annotation

Answer (score 7):

If you want to allow null values set

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="typeID", referencedColumnName="typeID")
```

to

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="typeID", referencedColumnName="typeID", nullable=true)
```

and you should let the column 'typeID' to be nullable also. (see [How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null))

If you don't want to have NULL's, just do the opposite.

Comment: as i said, i need that relation (invTypes table) only to get "names" by "id", it must not be deleted\add\edited in any cases

I don't understand how your code will help me

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the method setTypeID() in your entity, it's likely that this isn't setting the property as you're expecting, hence the null.

Answer (score 0):

Both `$invTypes_byTypeID` and `$typeID` properties maps to the same `typeID` column. You can't do this with doctrine.

I suggest that you remove the `$typeID` property, and instead of working with a 'type id', you work with the type instance and set it to the `$invTypes_byTypeID` property.

I guess that it would mean changing you form etc ...

Comment: so i must change $typeID (name) in MoonMaterial, that's it?

Comment: i changed all typeID names to userTypeID and.... still there is error on `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'userTypeID' cannot be null `