# MySQL integer default value 0

Tags: mysql, sql, integer

I have 4 integer columns in my table. They are not required to be filled. So some of them may be filled, some not.

When they are not filled, MySQL adds `0` to that column. I tried to change the column *default* value to `NULL` and it told "Invalid default value".

Is there any way to get an empty row without having there *zero*?

Comment: Please show `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table and how you insert new rows.

Comment: Are you sure the field is nullable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null)

Answer (score 5):

> "Is there any way to get empty row without having there the zero?"

To have NULL in the column by default use the following syntax in create table:

```
`column` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

To alter the existing column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN `column_name` `column_name` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your columns are NULL'able then it should work just fine

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Table1
    -> (id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    -> `col1` int, `col2` int, `col3` int, `col4` int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> INSERT INTO Table1 (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`)
    -> VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> INSERT INTO Table1 () VALUES();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to change your datatype into `varchar` and add default value NULL.

`ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ALTER COLUMN <column_name1> <datatype1> <constraint1>`

Comment: As long as the datatype is non-numerical, any form of String is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter your column to allow NULL values. This question has already been answered before:
[How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null)

Comment: That does not answer the question as it concerns a text column not an integer column