# How to insert NULL Value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert NULL Value in Database

```
$managerId = $_POST['managerId'];

if($managerId == 0)
{
    $managerId = NULL;
}
else
{
    $managerId = 14;
}
$mysql_user_resultset = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into user (managerId) VALUES ('$managerId')");
```

I am using like this. Its not working, Value doesn't insert.

How to insert both Null value and some value in Same variable..

Its Because of '$managerId' - single quotation.

How to define for both the types

Comment: add a null rule in your table strukture.

Comment: How to add. What is the rule

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: You should definitely be using prepared statements for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concatenate the $managerId variable, you are getting this query string:

```
"INSERT into user (managerId) VALUES ('')"
```

So, you are trying to insert an empty string. This is not what you want. The easiest way is to remove the quotes, like

```
"INSERT into user (managerId) VALUES ($managerId)"
```

This will work if your `managerId` field can be null, and still be valid for integer values.

Comment: `(string) NULL == ""`, not `"null"`.

Comment: you could check if the value is string using is_string add add the quotes to the variable.

Comment: Thanks cbuckley, I clearly got confused. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

PHP concatenates the null value as an empty string. So, to get it work, try this :

```
if($managerId == 0)
{
    $managerIdInQuery = 'NULL';
}
else
{
    $managerIdInQuery = 14;
}
$mysql_user_resultset = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into user (managerId) VALUES ($managerIdInQuery)");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the columns default value to NULL
2. Try this line:

   `$managerId = (int) $managerId; // Convert to INT to avoid SQL injection`
   `$mysql_user_resultset = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into user (managerId) VALUES (".($managerId?$managerId:'DEFAULT').")");`

If $managerId is set, $managerId will be inserted, elsewise the default value NULL.