# Integrity Constraint Violation - Null MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints, geocoding, nullable, integrity

I am geocoding several addresses but unfortunately I receive null values in the mySQL database that happens to break my script. I would like to allow null values in my database so I can fix the addresses manually afterwards. Is it possible to allow my current columns to allow null values without breaking my existing records?

The warning I see is: `Error! SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'coord_lat' cannot be null`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the column to allow null values (modify the below to suit your needs):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn VARCHAR(255);
```

(stolen from [How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null))

Answer (score 1):

Alter table and remove null integrity constraint on `coord_lat` column.