# how can we change a column from not nullable to nullable using sql

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue while entering data into column which has been set nullable false,How can I change this to nullable true using sql .I am using mysql database

Comment: [How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-)

Comment: Check out ALTER TABLE in MySQL doc

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
    CHANGE COLUMN MYCOLUMN MYCOLUMN VARCHAR(10) NULL;`

`MYTABLE` is the table name, `MYCOLUMN` is the column name. The important bit is the `NULL` at the end, that will make the column nullable. Note that you have to repeat the whole column definition. I used `VARCHAR(10)` in the example, but you have to adapt it to your column, setting default value and other options, if necessary.