# Saving form with not all properties

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony 2.8 with doctrine. I have entity with 3 properties. I would like to save form in database but only with 1 property. I created a form with 1 property but when I am trying to save it, error is shown:

An exception occurred while executing `INSERT INTO human (name, age, eyes) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` with params `["ss", null, null]`:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'age' cannot be null

Is it possible to do? I tried to set 'mapped'=> false option to underirable properties but it is not working.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: It is database issue, the column age is specified as NOT NULL. You need to  ALTER this column so NULL values are allowed. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null

Comment: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update`