# How can I validate my Other option in dropdown list?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, input, dropdown

How can I validate my Other **input field** in Laravel 4.2 which appears after choosing **Other** option in a **dropdown** list? The values from my dropdown list are already required, now I want to apply the same loggic of validation with errors on my input field so that both are **required**! By fulfilling the first validation rule from the dropdown list the second validation rule from the input field ouputs the error! Whats the easiest way to solve this!

```
<div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">



            <script type="text/javascript">
                function showfield(name){
                        if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input class="custom-input" placeholder="Roles" style="margin-left: 32px;" name="roles" type="text" value/>';

                        else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
                    }
            </script>



                <select id="otherField" name="role" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select role</option>
                    <option value="UI/UX designers">UI/UX designers</option>
                    <option value="QA engineers">QA engineers</option>
                    <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
                    <option value="Scrum Master">Scrum Master</option>
                    <option value="CEO">CEO</option>
                    <option value="Director">Director</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                    <div id="div1" class="row">
                           <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        @if($errors->first('roles') )
                                                            <div class="fe-form-error">
                                                                <div class="icon"></div>
                                                                {{ $errors->first('roles') }}
                                                            </div>
                                                        @endif
                                                        </div>

                    </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        @if($errors->first('role') )
                                                            <div class="fe-form-error">
                                                                <div class="icon"></div>
                                                                {{ $errors->first('role') }}
                                                            </div>
                                                        @endif
                                                        </div>

            </div>
```

My class with validation rules:

```
class OnEventRegistration extends AbstractValidator {

    protected $customRules = false;

    protected $rules = array(
        'email'             =>      'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'          =>      'required|min:8|confirmed',
        'first_name'        =>      'required',
        'last_name'         =>      'required',
        'role'              =>      'required',
        'roles'             =>      'required',

    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [required_if](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-required-if).

```
protected $rules = array(
    'email'             =>      'required|email|unique:users',
    'password'          =>      'required|min:8|confirmed',
    'first_name'        =>      'required',
    'last_name'         =>      'required',
    'role'              =>      'required',
    // This says required only if role = 'Other'
    'roles'             =>      'required_if:role,Other',
);
```

You'll likely also need another method of conditionally showing your `roles` input so that it's actually recognized as part of the DOM within your form.

```
<script>
function showfield(el) {
if (el.value == 'Other') {
    document.getElementById('roles').style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById('roles').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<select id="otherField" name="role" onchange="showfield(this)">
    <!-- options -->
</select>

<input id="roles" style="display: none; margin-left: 32px;" name="roles" type="text" placeholder="Roles" class="custom-input">
```

Comment: Tried already I get a **SQLSTATE[23000]**: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'roles' cannot be null

Comment: That's not at all related to any of the above code, but to solve this you need to change the `roles` column in your database to allow for null. If this was created with a migration then: `$table->string('roles')->nullable();` or in SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null

In MySQL columns are nullable by default. In Laravel using the built-in migrations, you need to specify which are nullable.

Comment: Working!!Thanks a lot for your effort! Appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help.