# change column definition in existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, alter

I need to edit a datatype (IS_NULLABLE) from my column tag.
Nothing works, i have tried like that:

```
ALTER TABLE veille
ALTER COLUMN tag
SET IS_NULLABLE false
```

or like that :

```
ALTER TABLE veille ALTER COLUMN tag Modify datatype false
```

but doesn't work too, i have this error :

```
 Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS_NULLABLE false' at line 3.
```

Edit : Resolved, the problem was my column has null values, i have changed these null values and all works fine.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE veille ALTER COLUMN tag SET NOT NULL` what if you try this?

Comment: Haven't used squirrel but shouldn't the sql look something like this? `ALTER TABLE veille 
ALTER COLUMN tag datatype NOT NULL`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Squirrel, but with the database you are using. Which DBMS is that? But there is no DBMS that has an error message that says "*doesn't work*". [edit] your question and add the **exact** error message you get.

Comment: i have as error : Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS_NULLABLE false' at line 3.

I have the same error with : ALTER TABLE veille ALTER COLUMN tag SET NOT NULL and with : ALTER TABLE veille ALTER COLUMN tag datatype NOT NULL

Comment: [edit] your question. Don't post additional information in comments (Did you do what the error message suggests? Read the manual?)

Answer (score 0):

try `ALTER TABLE veille_ndd_hist MODIFY tag bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0;`

you may also try `ALTER TABLE veille_ndd_hist CHANGE COLUMN tag tag BIT NOT NULL`

Note that when using MODIFY, you need to specify the full column definition, including DEFAULT value if was defined.

side note: **of course make sure that the column does not have any null values**

Comment: @Ygg69 what is the exact error and your axact syntax?

Comment: error is :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS_NULLABLE **NOT NULL**

and my syntax is :

Comment: sry fail and can't edit my post, my syntax is : 
ALTER TABLE veille_ndd_histo 
MODIFY tag IS_NULLABLE **NOT NULL**

Comment: @Ygg69 run this  **SHOW CREATE TABLE veille_ndd_histo**. and copy your column definition, then add the **NOT NULL**

Comment: Something like that ? 
SHOW CREATE TABLE veille_ndd_hist ALTER COLUMN tag BIT NOT NULL ?

Comment: @Ygg69 the SHOW CREATE TABLE... was just to assist you to get the correct column definition

Comment: ok thanks, ALTER TABLE veille_ndd_hist MODIFY tag BIT NOT NULL; modify my field 'column default' who is my default value, but i need to modify my field 'IS_NULLABLE', i need for that to modify tag then add set 'IS_NULLABLE' ?

Comment: @Ygg69 you do not have to explicitly update  'IS_NULLABLE'. the value of    'IS_NULLABLE' is **true** if your column definition doesn't have the **NOT NULL** part. and **false** if you have the **NOT NULL** part which I assume that is your desired result

Comment: I need to set the value 'NO', its for that i try to update this explicitly

Comment: @Ygg69 do you want tag to accept nulls or not accept nulls?

Comment: My colomn tag is boolean, true or false, the default value is false, and field 'is_nullable' is for not accept null.
But in the bdd, in this field 'is_nullable' all others column are already on 'yes' or 'no', so i can't set true or false.
Sorry if my english is bad

Comment: @Ygg69 sorry but I don't quite understand. lets forget about  'IS_NULLABLE' for a minute. How do you want **tag** to treat null values? do you want to accept or fail on NULL values?

Comment: I would like fail on null values

Comment: what happens when you run this? ALTER TABLE veille_ndd_hist MODIFY tag BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

Comment: When i run this i have this error :
Data Truncation error occurred on a write  of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred.

Comment: try ALTER TABLE veille_ndd_hist MODIFY tag BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT  false

Comment: I have tried too with false/true, i have the same error :/

Comment: please post the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE veille_ndd_hist on your post

Comment: i have this :
CREATE TABLE `veille_ndd_histo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `veille_ndd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titulaire` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `date_creation_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_expiration_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Comment: try this ALTER TABLE veille_ndd_histo MODIFY tag bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0

Comment: last kick at it would be the second option: ALTER TABLE veille_ndd_histo CHANGE COLUMN tag tag bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0'

Comment: I have already the same error :/ :
Data Truncation error occurred on a write  of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred.

Comment: sorry dude. hopefully somebody else can assist you, I'm out of ideas

Comment: no problem, thank you for your time and your help :)

Comment: @Ygg69 i think the problem is because you have some null values on your table. run **update veille_ndd_histo set tag = 0 where tag is null;** then do the alter statement

Comment: cool, glad you got it working at end. you may mark the answer

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ALTER TABLE veille ALTER COLUMN tag datatype
```

columns are nullable by default,  As long as the column is not declared UNIQUE or NOT NULL, there shouldn't be any problems.

refer to this question: [How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null)

Answer (score 0):

No need for `datatype false`
Just use the query like below

```
alter table table_name modify column tag <datatype> not null;
```

Comment: Thanks but this modify my field 'column default' in my column tag. And i would like modify my field 'IS_NULLABLE' in this same column