# Changing column nullability without specifying column type

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

Is it possible to change the nullable attribute of a column without specifying its data type? For example in the following statement I do not want to change the data-type yet I have to specify it.

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `throttle` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL;');
```

I mean in any RDBMS in particular MySQL.

Comment: That depends on the DBMS. Generally speaking, the ISO SQL specifications do not not standardise `ALTER` statements. However in all of the systems I've used you always need to provide a full column type definition.

Comment: You may be pertaining to an Oracle's alter table mytable modify(mycolumn null); or ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn DROP NOT NULL; But for MySQL, you have to indicate the data type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I modify a MySQL column to allow NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212939/how-do-i-modify-a-mysql-column-to-allow-null)

Comment: What did googling tell you?

Comment: @philipxy You may wonder but I love your comment. So funny.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar Thanks for your comments.Good to see at least one database provides such feature